# Question on locating a friend to the integer 273 (Friendly Numbers)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A friendly number or pair (m,n) satisfies $\frac{\sigma(m)}{m}=\frac{\sigma(n)}{n}$ and it is OEIS sequence A074902 for reference. My question is I need help if anyone is able to locate the friend of $273$. It is the 40th term in the sequence and unfortunately I cannot figure it out on my own as I am unable to code a program. If anyone can locate the friend much appreciated.
$\frac{\sigma(273)}{273}=\frac{64}{39}$

Comment: Please don't post questions that are easily answered by a simple web search, e.g. which [finds this table](http://upforthecount.com/math/ffp8.html) where your value is tabulated.

Comment: I did search, I apologize for not locating that but I do not appreciate your arrogance

Comment: Note also  that this is explicitly mentioned on the [OEIS A175907 page](https://oeis.org/A175907) for "known friendly squarefree numbers",  viz. "EXTENSIONS 
Added 273 as it is friendly with 2876211; 273 is a counterexample to the conjecture that 6 divides a(n). - Walter Nissen, May 28 2011"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A computer search reveals that the (smallest) friend is $2{,}876{,}211 = 3\cdot13^2\cdot31\cdot61$.

Comment: Please don't answer no-effort questions (esp. those that can be answered by  web search).

Comment: @BillDubuque where on the web can you find this answer?

Comment: I already posted one link above  on your question.